# Update play-services version in gradle file

Tags: android, google-play-services, build.gradle

I need to update the play-services version in the gradle file (smartphone), because i added a module wear. But when i remplace :

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'`

by

`'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'`

I have these messages :

`No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package`

and

`No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package`

Do you have an idea of where it may come ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have replaced the entire play services dependency with a wearable only one. It looks like you have ads? If this is the case add the following to your gradle dependencies:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'`

If you have any other play services you should look up their specific dependency [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and add them as well.

Comment: That's right, it works. So now, I have two gradle depandencies : wearable and ads. Just a last thing, do i have to add this one too : 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
' ?

Comment: No you don't need to. That would add ALL of the google play services. It's better to add the specific ones that you need, which is what we have done above.

Comment: Hi @shadyx if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.